# Equation for plane perpendicular to curve tangent hint

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> The (double) cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and plane $2x+3y+4z+2=0$ intersect along a closed curve. Determine and equation for the plane which is perpendicular to the curve tangent at the point $(3,4,-5)$. Hint: You may want to review the geometric properties of the vector product.

Here's my try:

$2x+3y+4z+2=0 \Leftrightarrow z=\frac{1}{4}(-2-2x-3y) $

Gives an intersecting xy-plane: $\frac{1}{16}(4 + 8 x - 12 x^2 + 12 y + 12 x y - 7 y^2)$ when inserting $z=...$ into the cone equation. Now how do I get the intersecting curve? Once I have the curve I just need to set the dot-product of the tangent-vector and the planes normal vector to equal 0 if I've understood this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about this problem is that you can determine the curve's tangent without explicitly determining the curve itself. Here's a hint to get you on your way. The two surfaces each have normal vectors at $(3,4,-5)$ which I will call $\mathbf{n}_1$ and $\mathbf{n}_2$, respectively. Since these vectors are normal to the surfaces, and the curve sits inside of the surfaces, they must both be normal to the curve as well, right? Anyway, that's my hint.

Also, I think you may have made a mistake in interpreting the problem: I think you are looking for the plane whose normal vector aligns with the curve's tangent. In this case, you definitely don't want the plane's normal vector to have $0$ dot product with the curve's tangent vector.

Comment: So, vector-product of $n_1$ and $n_2$ gives me the tangent-vector which is the planes normal-vector since the actual plane (not its normal vector) should be perpendicular to the tangent, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.